# How to Plot 2 Vectors in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, mplot3d

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "Qt4Agg"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

%matplotlib inline
p=np.array([1,-3,5])
q=np.array([3,2,6])
ax.quiver(p,q)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to plot the 2 vectors p and q in 3D. I keep getting this error message

> ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate

Not sure what I need to do to get this plot to show.

Answer (score 2):

`quiver` is for plotting a vector field (for example, the velocity field).

You can use plot to plot line between 0 and q (or p)

```
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0],p]).T)
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0],q]).T)
```

You can use quiver to add arrows at the end of the lines.

```
ax.quiver(*q,*q)
ax.quiver(*p,*p)
```

Comment: when I use plot the way you did I get this back 

Out[7]:
[<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D at 0xa235940>]

Also when I use quiver the way you did I get a syntax error

  File "<ipython-input-13-d30bfcdbc6bf>", line 1
    ax.quiver(*q,*q)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax